# Numpy: Use one array as an iterative test for elements in another array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, functional-programming

I have two arrays, `A` describes the start positions of 'blocks' of data, `B` describes absolute positions of things of interest in the non-blocked, raw data.

I want to be able to generate an index of the block-array `A` that match the location of elements identified in block `B`.

e.g.

```
import numpy as np
A = np.array([0,10,13,25,27,33,100])
B = np.array([3, 3, 5, 21, 27, 32, 74])
```

I want to return an array that looks like:

```
array([0, 0, 0, 2, 4, 4, 5])
```

That is, the array that describes the index-position, in terms of `A`, of the elements in `B`.

I could write a loop, something like:

```
list_holder = []
for e in B:
    list_holder.append(np.where(A>e)[0][0]-1)
np.array(list_holder)
```

But it turns out, for large arrays, this becomes rather slow - are there any functional or numpy-tricks that will perform this relatively simple operation as a one-liner?

Comment: [numpy.digitize](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.digitize.html#numpy.digitize)?

Comment: You can do this in O(N). Just write a function that iterates over the arrays in 1 pass. No need for an O(N^2) solution.

Comment: Good point above. *digitize* is more general about assumptions (your arrays are already sorted).

Answer (score 2):

Your solution is O(N^2).  But you can do this in O(N) simply by iterating over the lists in 1 pass as so.  I'm not a python guy, so if this code isn't "pythonic" that's why.

```
def digitize_sorted(a, b):
  j=0
  c = np.zeros(len(b))      
  for i in range(len(b)):
    while j < len(a) and a[j] <= b[i]:
       j += 1
    c[i] = j-1
  return c
```

Comment: Looks good to me although for some not huge N it will be beaten by digitize and more by the searchsorted-based answer (C-core vs .python-loops; despite differences in algorithmic-complexity). Maybe you should state your assumptions too to make the answer more complete.

Answer (score 1):

try `searchsorted()`:

```
A = np.array([0,10,13,25,27,33,100])
B = np.array([3, 3, 5, 21, 27, 32, 74])

np.searchsorted(A, B, side="right") - 1
```